# Web Essentials 2012 seems to be compiling LESS After Publish?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, web-essentials

So, after clicking one-click publishing, I see this in my output put window in VS2012:

```
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
9/10/2014 3:15:40 PM: ImportMixins.less compiled 
9/10/2014 3:15:40 PM: rs-ui-tabs-from-bulleted-list.less compiled 
9/10/2014 3:15:40 PM: ImportVariables.less compiled
9/10/2014 3:15:40 PM: variables.less compiled 
9/10/2014 3:15:40 PM: rs-custom-controls.less compiled
. 
.
.
```

This appears to me to be compiling LESS files after publishing my site. And indeed changes reflected in the CSS don't appear unless I manually compile the project before publishing or publish a second time.

Is there a way to ensure compilation before publishing other than doing a manual build prior to publish?  Or does anyone know of a work around?